# Serve dedicated HTML page to Google crawler without changing the URL to make for dynamic content

Tags: ajax, googlebot, google-crawlers

My website is in javascript with dynamically generated content on top of a fixed HTML frame. To make Google aware of the content I use the `_escaped_fragment_` [trick](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started) and track on the server side when to serve fixed content instead of dynamic. It all works well for the sub pages as long as they are linked with `#!`, which is the case for all pages but the homepage.

I obviously want to keep the homepage without an ugly `#!` at the end of the URL.

So far the only solution I can think of is to serve the homepage with fixed content instead of Ajax generated one for everyone.

I would rather keep the Google dedicated version branch separate from the common version as I don't maintain it as much, especially in terms of CSS and navigation, which do not matter that much.

Is there a way to figure out that it is Google crawling the website and serve a static version instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add the meta tag:

```
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

More details [there](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification).